# How to fetch data from Microsoft Custom Vision API using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, microsoft-custom-vision

I need some help regarding the use of Custom Vision. I built an image classifier in order to detect car damages.

So what I am trying to do: when I try to input an image and click the submit button, I want to be able to call the Custom Vision API and get the results in order to be able to analyze them later using ReactJS

I tried using AXIOS and the componentDidMount() method, but I can't seem to get a hold of them.

```js
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('url: "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/...",
                   // Request headers {
                     prediction:   ("Prediction-Key","xxx");
                     content:  ("Content-Type","xxx");
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    // Request body
                    data: imgContent,
                    processData: false')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Either you should use ```axios(url : "...", method : "POST")``` or ```axios.post('url....', {data...})``` . Also if you want to call this method onclick you do not have to call it inside componentDidMount method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your request type is post and you are using axios.get()

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your code, `// Request headers {
                    prediction:   ("Prediction-Key","xxx");
                    content:  ("Content-Type","xxx");
                   },`

The first bracket seems to be commented out so this may be a potential problem.

2. You should use async/await with the componentDidMount method.

An example

```
  async componentDidMount() {
const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`);
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json });
```

}